# Ubuntu 18.04 restarts abruptly

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

From last few days, my ubuntu installation shuts down abruptly.
I have no clue on what is causing this.

I tried few steps which I could gather and am attaching the log output as well. Can someone steer me in the right direction please?

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-74-generic Thu Jan  1 05:30 - 17:08 (4541+11:38)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-74-generic Tue Jun  8 16:15 - 17:08  (00:52)
myubuntu    :0           :0               Tue Jun  8 16:16 - 17:08  (00:52)
shutdown system down  5.4.0-74-generic Tue Jun  8 17:08 - 18:04  (00:56)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-74-generic Tue Jun  8 18:04   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-74-generic Tue Jun  8 18:05 - 18:17  (00:12)
myubuntu    :0           :0               Tue Jun  8 18:05 - crash (-4541+12:34)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-74-generic Thu Jan  1 05:30   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-74-generic Tue Jun  8 18:17   still running
myubuntu    :0           :0               Tue Jun  8 18:17    gone - no logout

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


myubuntu:~ grep -iv ': starting\|kernel: .*: Power Button\|watching system buttons\|Stopped Cleaning Up\|Started Crash recovery kernel' \
>   /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog /var/log/apcupsd* \
>   | grep -iw 'recover[a-z]*\|power[a-z]*\|shut[a-z ]*down\|rsyslogd\|ups'
grep: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 08:27:48 myubuntu rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="1092" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu kernel: [   16.148709] systemd-journald[435]: File /var/log/journal/876825fc89af4e0a835b842317a84125/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu systemd-fsck[789]: /dev/sda1: recovering journal
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu apparmor[854]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu dbus-daemon[1109]: dbus[1109]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu systemd[1]: Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.32.0]
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="1174" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:44 myubuntu thermald[1153]: sysfs write failed /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/enabled
grep: /var/log/apcupsd*: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:45 myubuntu NetworkManager[1154]: <info>  [1623126945.0979] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: 10-ubuntu-fan.conf, default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:46 myubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:48 myubuntu boltd[1711]: power: force power support: no
/var/log/syslog:Jun  8 10:05:49 myubuntu set-cpufreq[1160]: Setting powersave scheduler for all CPUs
myubuntu:~
```

Please do suggest if any other logs might help.

If nothing helps then I think my last option is to wipe down the installation altogether :(

Thanks
Vick

Comment: Posting selected lines from `/var/log/syslog` risks missing all the important details. Your best bet IMO, would be to look for a reboot line in the log and post a few hundred lines of `/var/log/syslog`  up to and including that reboot line: something must be happening to cause that reboot and you might find a hint in what's in the log *before* the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> systemd-fsck[789]: /dev/sda1: recovering journal

You got an unclean shutdown, so this is either some really bad software, or something's weird in hardware.

The most likely culprits are the power supply, the RAM and the CPU. All three might be negatively impacted by weather.

Try using lm_sensors to check CPU temperature. Also, if at all possible, stream the syslog to an external device so that you can recover the very last messages, which you're now currently almost certainly losing. If nothing else, as a last ditch try saving them with no write back and immediate flush to e.g. a SD card.

Something very similar happened to me three years ago at the beginning of the summer heat - gently cleaning the RAM contacts with isopropyl alcohol and re-seating the SODIMM chips was enough to fix everything (and the cleaning was probably overkill, at that).

Comment: Thanks @LSerni I executed the lm-sensors and found the following:                            
```asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2700 RPM
temp1:        +42.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ```

Comment: can you please guide me how can I set the stream the syslog to an external drive/SD card?

Comment: Temperature seems okay. Monitor it, but if it doesn't increase above 80 °C (and actually critical is 100 °C) it isn't the CPU overheating. This leaves RAM, power supply and possibly other hardware issues - as well as serious software glitches (which, unless you've updated some crucial kernel module, I'd discount).

Comment: You need to configure syslog (I'd wager you have syslog-ng), so use the "reliable" option and redirect the syslog file to /mnt/sdcard. Details you can find in the syslog-ng man page and in examples on their web site. Then mount /mnt/sdcard (or any external device) using the "sync" option in /etc/fstab. **The stream will be horribly slow**, which is why you only do this while testing.